# Hash and each method

Tags: ruby

I have a hash:

```
lines = {
   :n => ["Times Square", "34th", "28th", "23rd", "Union Square", "8th"],
```

When I do this:

```
first_line = lines[:n]
a = first_line[0]
b = first_line[4]
(a..b).select{|x| puts x}
```

I get an exceed limit. Is there a method to print just the range from `a` to `b`?

Hi All, You can stop marking me down grrr:) ... I forgot to up date my answer...
BTW another way for the above solution is

```
  lines = {
 :n => ["Times Square", "34th", "28th", "23rd", "Union Square", "8th"}

 puts first_line = lines[:n]
 puts first_line.slice(0, 5) => "Times Square", "34th", "28th", "23rd",  "Union Square"
```

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. I don't get an infinite loop with your code. In fact, your code does what you claim; it prints just the range within `a` and `b`.

Comment: ah... the "MTA" homework from GA... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It’s not infinite, but `'Times Square'` to `'Union Square'` is a very long range, involving `'Times Squarf'`, `'Times Squarg'`, and so on. If you want to get lines 0–4, it’s:

```
lines[:n][0..4].each { |x| puts x }
```